# Rendering svg in IE 7/8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg

Button displays fine in FF, Chrome, Safari. Will not render in IE 7/8.

Here's the code I've been given:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="RadMenu.css">
    </head>
  <body>
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
     <g id="g" shape-rendering="inherit" pointer-events="all">
     <circle cx="400" cy="210" r="25.6" fill="white" stroke="#505055" strokewidth="2">
     </circle>
       <foreignObject x="383" y="192" width="32" height="32" id="PBtn16400210">
         <html>
         <body>
            <div class="Btn3D" title="" style="width: 101%; height: 100%; background-color:   rgb(218, 184, 82); text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></div>
         </body>
         </html>
      </foreignObject></g>
     </svg> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've removed whole bunch of "I'm new here" text and added version of IE that you probably used. Feel free to update/revert changes. Also specify what exactly you want to work (i.e. SVG support in IE7).

Comment: Note that foreignObject isn't supported in the IE versions (IE9, IE10) that support svg natively.

Answer (score 4):

Internet Explorer didn't support SVG until v9 (and even then it was only basic support).

Comment: IE9 has pretty decent SVG support. I would say it's beyond basic.

Comment: I based that comment off Microsoft's description that it supports "the basic SVG feature set". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh410107.aspx

Comment: ahh. I think they are just being modest. I've done a lot of crazy SVG stuff lately and IE9 could handle almost everything I threw at it. I think it is fine for most uses

Answer (score 2):

[Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) does SVG to VML conversion for you, it understands native SVG. It doesn't sound like learning VML is worth it in your case.

One critical thing to note is that IE 9, nor 10 support foreign objects in SVG. Although optional in the SVG specifications, it can be a serious issue when supporting certain functionality. All other major browsers do support it. Your code will, in fact, not render correctly in any IE version.

Answer (score 0):

IE added support for SVG in IE9. Previous versions do not support it, and wont work. IE does support its own vector format called VML however, so it is possible to write polyfills. One such project is SVGWeb, which uses Flash to implement support. For what you need it should work well.

See http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using [Ample SDK](http://www.amplesdk.com) as a shim for your SVG content. An example: [SVG Tiger](http://www.amplesdk.com/examples/markup/svg/tiger/)

Comment: Does Ample support foreign objects in SVG?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution: adding this code after the SVG.

```
  <!--[if lte IE 8]><img src="image.png"><![endif]-->
```

(Source: https://j.eremy.net/inline-svg-with-ie8-fallback-support/)

On the testing html, the image between the top and bottom buttons is a SVG, blue. For Explorer 8 is a PNG, red.

```css
a {text-decoration:none}
button {
padding-bottom:2px;
width: 159px;
height: 29px;
border: 3px solid transparent;
border-radius: 75px;
color: #fff;
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1.25em;
margin: 0.75em auto;
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-TOP {border: #7766A6;
  background-color: #7766A6;
}

.btn-BOT {border:#F47320;
background-color: #F47320;
}

.CENTER {margin: 0 auto;
position:relative;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href=""><button class="btn-TOP" id="CT">TOP</button></a>

<p><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.1.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg class="CENTER" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="160px" height="30px"
  viewBox="0 0 159 29" enable-background="new 0 0 159 29" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <path fill="#0072BB" d="M17.7,0.6l11.5,14L17.8,28.4h123.4l-11.4-13.9l11.5-14H17.7z"/>
 <g>
  <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M51.3,15.8c0,1.9,0,3.2-0.1,4c-0.1,0.8-0.3,1.5-0.7,2.1c-0.4,0.6-1,1.1-1.7,1.5c-0.7,0.3-1.5,0.5-2.5,0.5
   c-0.9,0-1.7-0.2-2.4-0.5c-0.7-0.3-1.3-0.8-1.7-1.5s-0.7-1.4-0.8-2.1c-0.1-0.8-0.1-2.1-0.1-4v-3.2c0-1.9,0-3.2,0.1-4
   c0.1-0.8,0.3-1.5,0.7-2.1c0.4-0.6,1-1.1,1.7-1.5c0.7-0.3,1.5-0.5,2.5-0.5c0.9,0,1.7,0.2,2.4,0.5c0.7,0.3,1.3,0.8,1.7,1.5
   c0.4,0.7,0.7,1.4,0.8,2.1c0.1,0.8,0.1,2.1,0.1,4V15.8z M46.9,9.7c0-0.9,0-1.4-0.1-1.7c-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.4
   c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5,0.3c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.8-0.2,1.7v8.7c0,1.1,0,1.7,0.1,2c0.1,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.4c0.3,0,0.5-0.1,0.6-0.4
   c0.1-0.3,0.1-1,0.1-2.1V9.7z"/>
  <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M52.9,4.9H56c2.1,0,3.5,0.1,4.2,0.3c0.7,0.2,1.3,0.6,1.8,1.4c0.5,0.7,0.7,1.9,0.7,3.5
   c0,1.4-0.2,2.4-0.5,2.9c-0.3,0.5-1,0.8-1.9,0.9c0.9,0.2,1.5,0.6,1.7,1c0.3,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.6,1.1c0.1,0.3,0.1,1.3,0.1,2.8v4.9h-4.1
   v-6.2c0-1-0.1-1.6-0.2-1.8c-0.1-0.2-0.5-0.4-1.1-0.4v8.4h-4.4V4.9z M57.3,8.1v4.1c0.5,0,0.8-0.1,1-0.2c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.6,0.3-1.5v-1
   c0-0.6-0.1-1-0.3-1.2C58.1,8.2,57.8,8.1,57.3,8.1z"/>
  <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M68.8,4.9v18.6h-4.4V4.9H68.8z"/>
  <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M80.6,11.8h-4.4v-1.7c0-1.1,0-1.7-0.1-2c-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.6-0.4c-0.3,0-0.5,0.1-0.6,0.3
   c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.8-0.1,1.8v8.9c0,0.8,0,1.4,0.1,1.6c0.1,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.4c0.3,0,0.5-0.1,0.7-0.4c0.1-0.3,0.2-0.9,0.2-1.7v-2.2
   h-0.9v-2.8h5.1v10h-2.8l-0.4-1.3c-0.3,0.6-0.7,1-1.1,1.3c-0.5,0.3-1,0.4-1.6,0.4c-0.7,0-1.4-0.2-2.1-0.6c-0.6-0.4-1.1-0.9-1.5-1.5
   c-0.3-0.6-0.5-1.2-0.6-1.8c-0.1-0.6-0.1-1.6-0.1-2.9v-5.5c0-1.8,0.1-3.1,0.3-3.9c0.2-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-2.2c0.8-0.7,1.9-1,3.2-1
   c1.3,0,2.3,0.3,3.2,0.9C79.4,6,80,6.7,80.2,7.5c0.3,0.8,0.4,2,0.4,3.5V11.8z"/>
  <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M86.7,4.9v18.6h-4.4V4.9H86.7z"/>
  <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M98.2,4.9v18.6h-3.8l-2.3-8.5v8.5h-3.7V4.9h3.7l2.5,8.4V4.9H98.2z"/>
  <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M107.6,4.9l2.5,18.6h-4.5l-0.2-3.3h-1.6l-0.3,3.3H99l2.2-18.6H107.6z M105.2,16.9
   c-0.2-2.1-0.4-4.7-0.7-7.8c-0.4,3.6-0.7,6.2-0.8,7.8H105.2z"/>
  <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M115.2,4.9v14.9h2.7v3.7h-7.1V4.9H115.2z"/>
 </g>
 <g>
  <polygon fill="#FFFF00" points="146.9,5.1 149.4,10.1 154.9,11 150.9,14.9 151.9,20.4 146.9,17.8 141.9,20.4 142.9,14.9 138.9,11 
   144.4,10.1   "/>
  <polygon fill="#FFFF00" points="12.1,5.1 14.6,10.1 20.1,11 16.1,14.9 17.1,20.4 12.1,17.8 7.1,20.4 8.1,14.9 4.1,11 9.6,10.1   
   "/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
  
  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/juwfov/FLAG.png" class="CENTER">
<![endif]-->
</p>

<a href=""><button class="btn-BOT" id="CT">BOTTOM</button></a>
```

Test html:
https://danielillo.neocities.org/testSVG.html